# How to save string in a array char in c++?

Tags: c++

Why my program doens't runnning ?

This is my code

```
void tambahTeks(listTeks &LT, char C){
    addressT P = new elmListTeks;
    info(P) = C;
    next(P) = NULL;
    prev(P) = NULL;
    if(LTKosong(LT)){
        first(LT) = P;
        last(LT) = P;
    }else{
        next(last(LT)) = P;
        prev(P) = last(LT);
        last(LT) = P;
    }
}
```

and this

```
void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    char data[] = M;
    int pjg = M.length();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < pjg){
        tambahTeks(LT, data[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

error: initializer fails to determine size of 'data'

Comment: Why not `M.c_str()`?

Comment: Also what is going on with `next(P) = NULL` where that's presumably `P->next = NULL`.

Comment: 1. Why do you need `data`? Just do `tambahTeks(LT, M[i]);` 2. That should be `char* data = M.data()`, you'll have to resize if you insert/delete. That's bad.

Comment: @tadman c_str() returns a `const char*`

Comment: @theWiseBro That's all you're going to get out of a `std::string` unless you copy that to a mutable buffer instead. Unless this is CS50's "string" alias of course.

Comment: @tadman Last I checked c++17's `data()` returns `char*` as well

Comment: @theWiseBro Interestingly, but not sure it's a good idea to have a mutable pointer to that anyway. Asking for trouble.

Comment: Please provide a complete [repro], the verbatim error message, and indicate the line to which the error message points. Also explain *why* you need a `char[]`. If you index the `std::string`, you get a `char` to pass to `tambahTeks` as well.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. From the incomplete code you give, it is not possible to pinpoint the exact problem with the code. It is possible that the error lays in order portions of your code. Please try running your code through a debugger. You should identify the problematic portion of the code and see if you can solve the error by searching on the Internet. If not, extract the problematic code and make a [mre] (which can be fed directly to a compiler and demonstrate the problem) to demonstrate it. Make sure to tackle one specific issue and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you know that `string` itself, is somehow an array of chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char data[] = M;` is not a valid statement. You cannot initialize an array from a `std::string` like that.

You don't need a separate array at all. `std::string` is already a kind of array of chars, you just need a pointer to its data. You can use this instead:

```cpp
void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    const char *data = M.c_str();
    size_t pjg = M.length();
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i < pjg){
        tambahTeks(LT, data[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Or, you can get rid of `data` and just use `std::string`'s own `operator[]` instead:

```cpp
void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    size_t pjg = M.length();
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i < pjg){
        tambahTeks(LT, M[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Or, you can use iterators to iterate through the `std::string`:

```cpp
void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    auto iter = M.begin();
    auto end = M.end();
    while(iter != end){
        tambahTeks(LT, *iter);
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

Or, you can use the `std::for_each()` or `std::for_each_n()` standard algorithm:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    std::for_each(M.begin(), M.end(),
        [&](char ch) { tambahTeks(LT, ch); }
    );
}
```

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    std::for_each_n(M.begin(), M.length(),
        [&](char ch) { tambahTeks(LT, ch); }
    );
}
```

Or, you can use a range-based `for` loop:

```cpp
void bacaPesan(listTeks &LT, string M){
    for(char ch : M){
        tambahTeks(LT, ch);
    }
}
```